# How to update a global variable in Swift in a function

Tags: swift, function, global-variables

I am learning Swift and have a question about passing global variables into a function to be changed.

If I have a global variable declared like this in a class:

```
var autoCount = 0
```

Then I want to write some functions to manage updating it like:

```
func updateAutoCount {
    autoCount += 1
}
```

Is the above acceptable or should I make the function signature like this even though I'm passing a global variable that is readily available:

```
func updateAutoCount(autoCount: inout Int)  {
    autoCount += 1
}
```

BTW, I think autoCount should be a global rather than local variable because I want the scope to be global and want it to retain its value as long as the view is available rather than for the life of a function call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all syntactically fine as far as I can tell. The variable should be accessible, and since it's a var you should be able to increment it. However, from what you're describing (wanting a variable to exist as long as a view), you'd probably be better off subclassing the view and incrementing on that. Something like:

```
class AutocountingView: UIView {
    private var autoCount = 0

    func updateAutoCount() {
        autoCount += 1
    } 
}
```

The other option for having something be global (which is also frowned upon, but slightly less so), is to wrap it in a singleton pattern. So you would have something like:

```
class AutocountHelper {
    static let shared = AutocountHelper()
    var autoCount = 0

    func updateAutocount() {
        autoCount += 1
    }
}
```

which you could then access by `AutocountHelper.shared.updateAutocount()`.

Having a variable be global is generally not the safest idea, since you can end up with namespacing issues (and generally confusing code).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In this case I'm writing a demo app but I appreciate the best practice on using a singleton for the future.

Comment: No problem! Demo-app wise, global variable away... probably doesn't need to be quite as clean and safe in that case.